# Set default printer by vbscript on Server 2008 R2 RDS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, vbscript

I'm trying to get the Task Scheduler to run a vbscript that sets default printers for individual users on a Server 2008 R2 RDS machine.

Unfortunately my only success so far is getting any logon to trigger the script for my own user. Does anyone know how to make the scheduler triger the script for each user as they log in?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing you'd want to do with GPOs and/or logon scripts... why are you using VB?  And in any event, what account are you running the script as?  If you're running it as your user, that would explain why it only works for your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HopelessN00b was right that the script was only running for my user because of the task using my credentials. I was unaware that I could have the script run as a user group but once I figured that out I changed the running user to the Domain Users group and it worked for any user logging in. Although this problem was solved the project was scrapped in favor of a different solution. Thank you for your help though.